# Python Unit test library - ParseError: Expecting a string <MagicMock name='ClassPage.json.get()'

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, mocking

I am trying to add a mock a parameter but I don't know where I'm going wrong.

This is the method where I'm trying to mock 'klass' which basically represents has a class called ClassPage which has different values(no methods)

```
class GrapheneHelper():

    @staticmethod
        def convert_time_field(klass, field, default=None):

            time = GrapheneHelper.get_json_field(klass, field, default)

            if time is None:
                return None
            else:
                return iso8601.parse_date(time)
```

This is the test where I'm patching the ClassPage:

```
@patch('gql.pages.content_page.ClassPage')
def test_convert_time_field(self, mock_klass):
    """ Return YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:FF in iso8601 format """

    mock_klass.json = {'time_field': '2017-09-18T23:09:33'}
    expected_time = iso8601.parse_date('2017-09-18 23:09:33')

    self.assertEqual(GrapheneHelper.convert_time_field(mock_klass, field='time_field', default=None), 'expected_time')
```

The error I get: `ParseError: Expecting a string <MagicMock name='ClassPage.json.get()' id='4644743312'>`

I feel like I'm REALLY close, but I haven't been able to figure out what's wrong. I've tried MagicMock, read the documentation and even some blogs without any luck. Any advise would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you have given, this is what I think is happening:

`GrapheneHelper.get_json_field` calls the function `ClassPage.json.get()`

So mock the the return value of the `get()` function:

```
@patch('gql.pages.content_page.ClassPage')
def test_convert_time_field(self, mock_klass):
    """ Return YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:FF in iso8601 format """

    mock_klass.json.get.return_value = 'something expected'

    time = '2017-09-18T23:09:57Z'
    expected_time = '2017-09-18 23:09:57+00:00'

    self.assertEqual(GrapheneHelper.convert_time_field(mock_klass, time, default=None), expected_time)
```

Comment: TY - you help me understand what my error was. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Also, I ended up adding the ```iso8601.parse``` to the expected time:
 ```expected_time = iso8601.parse_date('2017-09-18 23:09:33')``` - I updated my question with the changes